# Reload collectionview with two types custom cells using segmented control

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to achieve the following behaviour with 2 types of custom collection-view cells, lets call it A and B:

I have a segmented control with 2 options, images and music. When I click on the images option, the collection-view will show me the images by using custom cell A, when I click on music, it will reload the table and will show me the music by using custom cell B. This happens by using the same collection-view.

My problem is that I get the following error:

> could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with
>   identifier PictureCell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

My current code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        switch mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            let nibPicture = UINib(nibName: "PictureCell", bundle: nil)
            myCollectionView.register(nibPicture, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for:indexPath) as! PictureCollectionViewCell
            let fruits: [MyItem] = dataSource.itemsInGroup(indexPath.section)
            let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]

            let name = fruit.name!
            cell.fileImage.image = UIImage(named: name.lowercased())

            return cell
        case 1:
            let nibMusic = UINib(nibName: "MusicCell", bundle: nil)
            myCollectionView.register(nibMusic, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for:indexPath) as! MusicCollectionViewCell
            let fruits: [MyItem] = dataSource.itemsInGroup(indexPath.section)
            let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]

            let name = fruit.name!
            cell.labelAuthor.text = name
            cell.labelMediaName.text = name
            return cell
        default:
            let nibPicture = UINib(nibName: "PictureCell", bundle: nil)
            myCollectionView.register(nibPicture, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for:indexPath) as! PictureCollectionViewCell
            let fruits: [MyItem] = dataSource.itemsInGroup(indexPath.section)
            let fruit = fruits[indexPath.row]

            let name = fruit.name!
            cell.fileImage.image = UIImage(named: name.lowercased())

            return cell
        }
    }
```

The initial load of the images works fine but when I change to music It crashes.
Here is a demo showing the problem: [Demo Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i48sa42hsa2iyi3/collectionTest.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Did you set the proper `ReuseIdentifier` in the _nib_ file?

Comment: I don't understand: You register in `cellForItemAt:`? Why? Also, you register with cell identifier "Cell", but afterwards you ask for cell identifier "PictureCell" or "MusicCell". It's not logic.

Comment: What's `ItemCell` ? Where is it declared? Why is it here?

Comment: Each custom cell presented here on its own loads well, but when I try to change the collection-view to load another custom cell it gives the error: Could not cast value of type '.PictureCollectionViewCell' (0x1001816b0) to '.MusicCollectionViewCell' (0x100180bd0).

Comment: I have created a demo app for you guys to see the problem, edited the main post with it.